# How to use Graphics.DrawMesh?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, rendering, mesh

I tried to draw a mesh in Editor mode (Scene view) and found `Graphics.DrawMesh` on Google.

But everybody suggested using `Graphics.DrawMeshNow` instead.

But unfortunately `DrawMeshNow` does NOT interact with lights.

I have tried to put the code inside

```
Update()
OnPreRender()
OnPostRender()
OnPreCull()
OnEnable()
OnDisable()
OnRenderObject()
OnDrawGismos()
OnGUI()
```

I also tried to add `[ExecuteInEditMode]`, and move the script around to different GameObjects (The camera itself and other GameObjects).

But I could never make it appear in Scene View.

I also tried to find if there is anything that will force the `Graphics.DrawMesh` to draw immediately but to no avail.

I also tried to use `Gizmos.DrawMesh`, and it works alright, but I can not assign any materials to it.

So, could somebody please be so kind teaching me how to make `Graphics.DrawMesh` work?

PS. My environment is HDRP, but I have made sure the shader of the material is set to HDRP/Lit, so I don't think that's the problem.

### Update

I have figured out "something", even though I have absolutely no idea why:

If I put `DrawMeshNow` in `OnDrawGismos` and attach it to the camera (`DrawMesh` is still not working), and set the pass with `Material.SetPass` to 2, it will work with solid-color materials without alpha channel.

And if I set it to 8, it'll work on all materials (including the alpha channel), but the "culling" is set to "front" (meaning the normals of the whole mesh are flipped and I could only see the "backside/inside" of the mesh) and I can not change it from `Cull Mode`, and none of the `Mesh.RecalculateBounds(), Mesh.RecalculateNormals(), Mesh.RecalculateTangents()` works.

And if I set it to 9, it'll work on Transparent materials (Surface Type was set to Transparent), and if I didn't check `Depth Write`, the mesh will be "seethrough" (even if the alpha is set to 255).

Everything else does not work (I have only tested up to 120).

I'll keep testing and see if I could find a normal-working pass.

### Update 2

OK, I guess I could make it work by setting the pass to 9 and changing the material to `Transparent` and checking `Depth Write`, even though I don't know the "reason" behind it (so I guess you could call it a "hack").

But still, `DrawMeshNow` does not interact with lights, so I still need advice to make `DrawMesh` work.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Graphics.DrawMeshNow` within `OnDrawGizmos` ?

Comment: Yes, I did! Sorry I forgot to add it to the list, I'll go add it now.

Comment: Why not instantiate an object instead?